# Keep single instance application maximized after restore

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a VB .NET application set as single instance. When I try to launch the application the second time its window is restored to its normal windowed state instead of being maximized (like it was before attempting the second launch). How can I make the application window to preserve its last state?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Nothing is automatic here, beyond the StartupNextInstance event.  If you are doing anything to the main form in an event handler for that event, like restoring it, then that's where the problem is located.  Post your code, we can't guess at what it looks like.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I do not use the StartupNextInstance event at all. I just checked the "Single instance application" porperty at the project settings to enable single instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can save last state in registry or a file when it's changed, and apply it when you load your app

To set and get registry values check this :

```
  Public Function GetRegistryValue(ByVal KeyName As String, Optional ByVal DefaultValue As Object = Nothing) As Object
        Dim res As Object = Nothing
        Try
            Dim k = My.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\YourApp", True)
            If k IsNot Nothing Then
                res = k.GetValue(KeyName, DefaultValue)
            Else
                k = My.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\YourApp")
            End If
            If k IsNot Nothing Then k.Close()
        Catch ' ex As Exception
            'PromptMsg(ex)
        End Try
        Return res
    End Function

    Public Sub SetRegistryValue(ByVal KeyName As String, ByVal _Value As Object)
        Try
            Dim k = My.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\YourApp", True)
            If k IsNot Nothing Then
                k.SetValue(KeyName, _Value)
            Else
                k = My.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\YourApp")
                k.SetValue(KeyName, _Value)
            End If
            If k IsNot Nothing Then k.Close()
        Catch ' ex As Exception
            'PromptMsg(ex)
        End Try
    End Sub
```